# What is the chromatic index of a complete graph with its edges doubled?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

If $G$ is a graph, let $G'$ denote the graph obtained by doubling each edge of $G$. How can I show that $\chi'(G')=2\chi'(G)$?

I am considering the two cases when $G$ is a complete graph $K_n$ with $n$ odd or even. If $n$ is odd then, I know that $\chi'(G)=\chi'(K_n)=n$ and $n+1$ if $n$ is even. I also showed in a previous problem that $\chi'(G')\leq 2\chi'(G)$ giving an upper bound. So, I need to give a lower bound for the chromatic index. If each edge is doubled, then $\Delta(G')=2\Delta(G)$. This is how far I got. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Take $C_5$, the cycle graph of length 5.

We have $\chi'(C_5) = 3$.

Let $C_5'$ be the graph obtained after doubling the edges of $C_5$.

You should be able to show that $\chi'(C_5') = 5 < 2 \cdot 3$.

Comment: The last part of the answer needs clarification. E.g. for the cycle $C_3$ of length $3,$ we get $\chi'(C_3) = \Delta(C_3) + 1=3,$ and $\chi'(C_3') = 6 = \Delta(C_3')+2$ after doubling the edges. More generally, if each edge of $C_3$ is replaced by $n$ parallel edges, then the chromatic index becomes $\chi'=\Delta + n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ (famously due to Catlin). Apparently the attempted answer assumes, incorrectly, that the version of Vizing's theorem for simple graphs holds also for multigraphs.

Comment: @TommyR.Jensen You are entirely correct.  Bad old me, jumping to conclusions too quickly.  I'll leave the counter-example there, and paste the erroneous argument here for historical purposes.  The following is incorrect:  "The thing is that for $G$, either $\chi'(G) = \Delta(G)$ (class 1), or $\chi'(G) = \Delta(G) + 1$ (class 2).  That's Vizing's theorem.
But if $\Delta(G') = 2\Delta(G)$, then $\chi'(G') \leq 2\Delta(G) + 1$.  But if $G$ is of class 2, the theorem would state that $\chi'(G') = 2(\Delta(G) + 1) > 2\Delta(G) + 1$, a contradiction."